# MySQL 5.7 error while starting on Centos7

Tags: mysql, ssh, centos7, postfix-mta

I am getting an error while starting MySQL 5.7 on Centos7:

```
-- Unit mysqld.service has begun starting up.
Mar 30 11:07:24 my_hostname postfix/smtpd[361229]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 11:07:24 my_hostname postfix/smtpd[361229]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 11:07:24 my_hostname postfix/smtpd[361229]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 11:07:24 my_hostname sshd[382098]: Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 37426 on 127.0.0.1 port 22475
Mar 30 11:07:24 my_hostname sshd[382098]: Did not receive identification string from 127.0.0.1 port 37426
Mar 30 11:08:24 my_hostname postfix/smtpd[361229]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 11:08:24 my_hostname postfix/smtpd[361229]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 11:08:24 my_hostname postfix/smtpd[361229]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 11:08:24 my_hostname sshd[382267]: Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 37570 on 127.0.0.1 port 22475
Mar 30 11:08:24 my_hostname sshd[382267]: Did not receive identification string from 127.0.0.1 port 37570
Mar 30 11:08:41 my_hostname mysqld[381961]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Mar 30 11:08:41 my_hostname systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 30 11:08:41 my_hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has failed
```

Does anyone has anything in mind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue sorted. It was a company police restriction.

Thank you.